# How to get rid of quotes in a json string resulting from converting scientific notation to exact value

Tags: python, sql, json

I have a list of dictionary items that I will iterate through to update into a dictionary. That dictionary will be converted to a json string which will get inserted into an SQL database. My problem is that some of those values in the dictionary items can be very small (or large), and thus Python automatically puts it in scientific notation.

For example, I have this dictionary: `{"Name": {"Key1": "0.000006", "Key2": "0.0000000001"}}`. I've been able to convert scientific notation to an exact value string using the function that I created below. But now I have to keep it as a string because as soon as I cast `float()` on that string, it goes back to scientific notation. So then when I use `json.dumps()` to put the dictionary into a json string, it creates unnecessary quotes around those string-casted float values: `"{"Name": {"Key1": "0.000006", "Key2": "0.0000000001"}}"`. How do I get rid of those quotes?

```
def format_float(self, value):
    value_string = str(value)
    # Anything smaller than or equal to 1e-5 will get converted to scientific notation
    # If the value is in scientific notation
    if 1e-323 <= abs(value) <= 1e-5:
        # Split the string by the exponent sign
        split_value_string = value_string.split("e-")
        # Get the exponential
        exponential = int(split_value_string[1])
        # If there is a decimal, there could be digits after the decimal
        if "." in split_value_string[0]:
            precision = len(split_value_string[0].split(".")[1])
        else:
            precision = 0
        f = "%.*f" % (exponential + precision, value)
    elif value == float("inf") or value == float("-inf"):
        return value
    # Not in scientific notation
    else:
        if "." in value_string:
            precision = len(value_string.split(".")[1])
        else:
            precision = 0
        f = "%.*f" % (precision, value)
    # No decimal
    if "." not in f:
        f += ".0"

    p = f.partition(".")

    s = "".join((p[0], p[1], p[2][0], p[2][1:].rstrip("0")))  # Get rid of the excess 0s

    return s
```

Comment: "*as soon as I cast float() on that string, it goes back to scientific notation*" - I think there is a misunderstanding here. That isn't what `float()` does. Can you create a short, standalone program that demonstrates how `float()` causes it to go back to scientific notation?

Comment: @Rob Something like this `print(float("0.00000000000000000000001"))`. I get `1e-23`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`float()` shouldn't be putting anything in scientific notation. It's just that when python prints a `float` that's really long, it prints it in scientific notation. try using `json.dumps()` while keeping the values as `float`, it should give you what you want.

**edit**: let me rephrase. `json.dumps()` will give you valid json. the json specification allows for floats to be given as scientific notation, so the fact that it's in scientific notation shouldn't be a problem. That is, if you load what has been dumped, it will give you a `float`, which you can do math on as you would expect. e.g.: `type(json.loads(json.dumps({'lol':1e-8}))['lol'])` gives me `float`

If you REALLY need to have the json not have scientific notation in it, for example if the thing that will read the json is not standards-compliant, then you can use `json.dumps()` to dump it as a string, then use `re.sub()` to replace the numbers.

```
precision = 10
re.sub('\d+e-?\d+',lambda x: '%.*f'%(precision,float(x.group())),json.dumps({'lol':1e-8}))
```

gives me

```
'{"lol": 0.0000000100}'
```

Comment: @OP said that they already tried that. When `json.dumps` converts everything to a string, it converts “significant” floating point numbers to scientific notation just as the REPL would do if you simply typed in the number.

Comment: @phsyron Can you expand on that? If I try something like `print(json.dumps({"lol": 1e-8}))`, it outputs `{"lol": 1e-08}` which isn't converted.

Comment: @physyron Thanks, that's good enough for me. I originally thought about re.sub to replace floats, but other keys in the dictionary can be floats too, which will cause unnecessary alteration. I should've put that in my post. I didn't think about putting the scientific notations in there, then converting. +1 and accepted. Btw, your regex expression doesn't account for decimals, so `{'lol':1.5e-8}` will give me `{"lol": 1.0.0000000500}`. Use `(\d*\.)?\d+(e[+-]?\d+)?` instead. :)

Comment: @Don what are you using the json for that won't accept scientific notation?